# Why does Tor need to use onion routing instead of decrypting then re-encrypting when passing to the next node?

Tags: encryption

I understand why Tor needs many nodes in each relay, although in the case of connecting a hidden server, the packet is encrypted end to end.

So why then must there be multiple layers of encryption on top of that with nodes decrypting the next layer then passing it, instead of only encrypting one layer that the next node decrypts, then re-encrypts with the shared key of the next node and so on?

Comment: While this question needs to be improved, it seems to be a valid architectural design question.  I'm not seeing a reason to close this.  If you think this is not a valid question here, please comment as to why.

Comment: What I would recommend here is have a paragraph where you explain how you understand the Tor encryption to work.  Then write another paragraph where you describe what you think would work instead.  Right now, you have a run-on sentence explaining both and I think it's a little tough to parse.

Comment: Watch this: https://youtu.be/QRYzre4bf7I

Comment: You might get more informed answers on [security.se].  I recommend deleting this question and posting there instead.

Answer (score 3):

Without transport encryption, any node in the chain would be able to de-anonymize sender.